# Relative URLs inside of Base64 Encoded SVG's do not work

Tags: html, image, url, svg, path

I have two ways I can load an svg - via a link or via an inline base 64 encoded data string.

Now consider that the svg has an image embedded inside which links to another svg on the same server.

For some reason when the nested image's link is an absolute path, it won't render.   However, if the link is a fully qualified url, then it will render.

Why?

```html
<!-- base 64 loading -->
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,..." />

<!-- url loading -->
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/some.svg" />

<svg>
    <image x="10" y="20" width="80" height="80" xlink:href="/path/a.svg" /><!-- works only with url loading -->
    <image x="10" y="20" width="80" height="80" xlink:href="http://localhost/path/a.svg" /><!-- works with both url and base64 loading -->
</svg>
```

Comment: What do you think the relative URL is relative to? The data URL is a standalone object.

Comment: Typically the relative URL (e.g. "/path/a.svg") - with a leading slash - will resolve to the same domain that is serving the content, which in my case should be (http://localhost/).

Comment: No, there is no domain loading content of a data URL.

Comment: Interesting, so data urls don't know the domain it's under, but linked resources do.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs Note: Data URLs are treated as unique opaque origins by modern browsers, rather than inheriting the origin of the settings object responsible for the navigation.